# Calling JComboBox with JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jcombobox

I´m new in creating GUI in Java, I would like to implement JComboBox (which uses GlazedLists), in my JFrame, which is in another class. Is it possible to call this JComboBox in my JFrame? I´m asking because I use NetBeans (some parts of code are forbidden to edit). Thanks

Comment: Please specify what you mean by calling the JComboBox...accessing the variable? If yes, the answer to your question is basically "Yes"

Comment: I want to call somehow this class http://publicobject.com/glazedlistsdeveloper/screencasts/autocompletesupport/AutoCompleteSupportExample.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the reference to the `JComboBox` like any other variable.  The name of the combo boxes variable will depend if your reamed the object or not (you can do this from the form inspector, usually found under the projects window when in design mode)

While you can't modify the code in the protected blocks, you still effect he combo box (or any other component) within your code normally, just make sure `initComponents` has been called first